# Why getting relation not found error in postgres with spring jpa?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a spring mvc project where I am using JPA.Now when I try to interact with the DB postgres I get a error stating that:

```
relation "public.clients" does not exist\n  Position: 422
2021-07-22 17:47:25 [@] ERROR GenericControllerAdvice: Exception StackTrace:
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

Here are my code:

`Client Entity`:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "clients",schema = "public")
    
    public class ClientModel {
    
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private BigInteger client_id;
        private String client_name;
        private String client_secret;
        @OneToMany(targetEntity = ClientGrants.class,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private List<ClientGrants> apis_granted;
        private String status;
        @CreatedDate
        @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
        private Date created_at;
        private String created_by;

//setters and getters

}
```

Here's my JPA configs:

```
<bean id="jacksonObjectMapper" class="com.insta.hms.common.CustomObjectMapper">
        <property name="PropertyNamingStrategy"
            value="#{T(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.PropertyNamingStrategy).SNAKE_CASE}" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    >
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hs" />
        <property name="username" value="postgres" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.proj.app.first.clients" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="persistenceProvider">
            <bean class="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
        <qualifier value="jpaTransactionManager"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect</prop>
                <!-- This property prints the SQL statements executed by hibernate -->
                 <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <!-- This property is used to make the SQL statements a bit more readable -->
                <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
                <!-- This formats the SQL before it prints it  -->
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>

            </props>
        </property>
```

In postgres under `hs` database:

I have multiple schemas `public`,`cen`,`quartz`.I hava specified the schema to be `public`.Its the default schema present in postgres.

Can someone help me with it?
Thanks

Comment: Have you made sure the tables are actually there? Hibernate needs to be run in the "create-drop" mode for this to work.

Comment: do i need to make the tables first? doesnt jpa does it for me?

Comment: I think you have to tell Hibernate to use "create-drop" in the properties and then it will generate the tables.

Comment: its not working even then

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace. Enable logging and post the SQL statement if it isn't included in the stack trace. Finally post the DDL of the tables in your database.